# Spring Framework - Kotlin - Save Entity to XML

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I would like to create an XML file in the Spring Framework at the push of a button and download it.
This file should be downloaded from an existing entity.
Unfortunately I can't find anything about how this works with Kotlin and the Spring Framework.

Can someone show me an example here?

I have tried https://grokonez.com/kotlin/kotlin-convert-kotlin-object-xml-file-xml-string-jackson but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Sie erhalten möglicherweise bessere Antworten, wenn Sie die Frage auf Englisch stellen

Comment: Sorry - my fault - corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Jackson-dataformat-xml is a good option.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.io.File

class XmlMapperTest {
    @Test
    fun serializeToXml() {
        val xmlMapper: XmlMapper = XmlMapper()

        val car1 = Car(-1, "UAZ", CarColor.GREEN)

        val xml: String = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(car1)

        assertEquals("<Car><id>-1</id><model>UAZ</model><color>GREEN</color></Car>", xml)

        File("F:/car1.xml").writeText(xml)
    }

    data class Car(
            val id: Long,
            val model: String,
            val color: CarColor
    )

    enum class CarColor {
        GREEN, RED
    }
}
```